# MD5 hashing 4-byte and 8-byte keys into 16-byte values; what's the chance of a collision?

Tags: md5, hash, collision

I have 2<sup>32</sup> 4-byte keys that I'm hashing; what's the chance of collision?

What if I have 2<sup>64</sup> 8-byte keys (not really storing *every* key, but I want to know the worst case)?

Comment: Is this homework? Whether it is or not, what have you figured out so far?

Comment: What are you using to store 2**64 keys? Is it affordable? I'd like to be able to store that much data…

Comment: `@Felix Kling:` This isn't homework; I've worked out the general formula (probability that at least two keys are the same) for *n* random keys drawn from a discrete uniform distribution with range [ 0 , *d* ]. It works for small numbers, but *n* = 2^32 and *d* = 2^128 is too big.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867191/probability-of-sha1-collisions (just change the variables to match MD5's hash space)

Comment: `@Donal Fellows:` I'm not storing *every* key from 0 to 2^64; I'm just trying to figure out the worst case.

Comment: `@bdonlan:` I know the general formula ( *n* = 2^32, *d* = 2^128 ). These are very specific values for *n* (4-byte or 8-byte keys), but very large, so I can't plug them into the formula.

Comment: If the formula is n*(n-1)/(2**(b+1)) then with large n, take n==n-1 so you get 2**64/2**129 == 2**-65

Comment: @Super: There's worst case and there's being ridiculous.

Answer (score 3):

Per [the wikipedia page on the Birthday Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Approximations), a good first order approximation can be found with `1-e^(-(n^2)/d)`. Graphing this for your values gives [this graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B1-e%5E%28-%28%282%5Ex%29%5E2%29/%282%5E128%29%29,+%7Bx,+50,+64%7D%5D) (logarithmic horizontal axis, I've zoomed in on where the probability starts to spike). Note that this is only an approximation, and should be considered conservatively (ie, the real probability may be somewhat higher, but it should be in the right ballpark).

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing with the hash codes? If you're using them to work out whether two pieces of data are the same, an MD5 hash is pretty good, though only if you are working with data that is not being created by malicious entities. (Cryptographic purposes need better hash algorithms precisely in order to deal with the "malicious attacker" problem.)

If you're using them for building a map (i.e., you're building a hash table) it's usually better to use a cheap hash and come up with a way to mitigate the costs of collision (e.g., by hanging a linked list off the hash table and resizing/rebuilding when the average weight gets too large).