# Collision rates for trimmed SHA1- hashes

Tags: hash-collision

With my webapp I'm storing cached files with a hash generated filename in various subdirectories to optimize performance levels. One way I know that I could improve performance also would be to ensure that the generated names follow a 8.3 filename structure so NTFS doesn't have to generate short filenames (I won't be able to set that in the registry).

In order to do that though I would have to trim the hash (I was thinking SHA1) to 8 characters, obviously this will increase the probability of collision substantially. What I would like to know is what is the probability of collision?

I've seen the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867191/probability-of-sha1-collisions) on full SHA1 hash collision rates but my maths is terrible so calculating the value is way beyond me.

Comment: That all depends on how many bytes you are fitting in 8 characters. Is it stored base16 (hexadecimal) or something more complex like base 32?

Comment: Additionally, [you can disable](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/121007/en-us) the automatic creation of 8.3 file names on NTFS. So rather than change your code, you can just turn the NTFS feature off.

Comment: @vcsjones Unfortunately like I said, that wont be possible for me. On your first question, it would be two bytes per character, I don't know if that helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `SHA-1`'s output is uniformly distributed, you can approximate the collision rate using the Birthday Paradox:

Assume you keep `n` bits of the `SHA-1` output, there is a ~50% chance that you would have a collision in a set containing `2^(n/2)` records, or in other words your collision rate is approximately `1/2^(n/2)`

If you need a more accurate answer, you can always use the formula in the answer you've referenced in your question.

So here, if we assume each character is 1 Byte (8 bits), then you will most likely encounter a collision if you have ~`2^(8*8/2) = 4294967296` records (therefore the collision rate is going to be `2.32 * 10^-8` which is **very** small).

Considering the collision rate you have discovered using your test program, the `ToSHA1Fingerprint()` function returns a Hexadecimal string which means an 8 character sub-string of it only represents 4 bytes and hence the approximate collision rate based on the above formula is `1/2^(4*8/2) = 0.000015258789` or `0.002%`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the collision rate  is too high for my needs anyway, I'm getting ~0.004% testing using the following code.

```cs
const int Iterations = 10;
const int Maxitems = 360000;

for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
{
    List<string> paths = new List<string>();

    for (int j = 0; j < Maxitems; j++)
    {
        string path = Path.GetRandomFileName().ToSHA1Fingerprint()
                                              .Substring(0, 8);

        paths.Add(path);
    }

    int count = paths.Distinct().Count();

    double collisionRate = ((Maxitems - count) * 100D) / Maxitems;
    collisions.Add(collisionRate);
}

double averageCollisionRate = collisions.Average();
```