# I have the hashed password (algorithm SHA1) and Password salt, would I be able to retrieve the password?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, encryption, password-encryption

I am just curious if this can be done.

I have the hashed password (algorithm SHA1) and Password salt, would I be able to retrieve the password?

Can it be done in SQL server or can it be done via any software?

example:

```
 Hashed GQdsHCOcun8JuysvqsM3pP0eeoU=
 Password salt: CDjIsQcbz23NzXZLzHRTVw==
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Hashes are one-way functions. You can [brute-force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack) the passwords, until you guess the correct password, but you cannot decrypt them.

Comment: Alex W is correct.  Having the hashed password and the salt, confirm whether or not a given password is correct.  However, you cannot (easily) figure out what the original password is, with only the hashed password and the salt.

Comment: @NoviceDeveloper - As Alex said you cannot decrypt a hash, however you can brute-force about [3 Giga](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat/#performance) SHA1 hashes per second with common hardware. That means that SHA* is not appropriate to hash passwords, instead one should use a slow key-derivation function like BCrypt or PBKDF2.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no.  SHA1 is a one way hash algorithm.  You could theoretically find other words that also produce the same hash (collisions), but it would take a lot of time and computing resources.

Comment: For those curious about collisions, you can see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867191/probability-of-sha1-collisions) about their probability.