# Using SHA1 to verify user's email - PHP

Tags: php, sha1

So essentially the question is, can I use a SHA1 hash to send a verification email to a new user with little chance of duplicate hash?

I want to send a user this email:    `www.example.com/verify.php?hash=[40 digit sha1 hash]`

as opposed to sending them this emai: `www.example.com/verify.php?user=123456&hash=[40 digit sha1 hash]`

I want to avoid sending a second user parameter.

The hash is created as such:

```
$verifyHash = sha1[$uid.$email.date('r')];
```

Where `$uid` is unique, `$email` is unique and `date('r')` is as unique as possible with unix timestamp.

What do you think the chances are of duplicate hashes being created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sufficiently close to zero to ignore.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867191/probability-of-sha1-collisions)

However, you should additionally add some randomness using `mt_rand`. The exact time on your server is easy to guess, and email and UID are known to malicious users.

Comment: so add mt_rand to my value?  such as `$verifyHash = sha1[$uid.$email.date('r').mt_rand()];` ?

Comment: would you still add the ?user=12345 parameter to the email? Or do you not foresee someone flooding the verify.php with random sha1 hashes for kicks

Comment: Yes (adding `mt_rand()` like that is fine), no (it's not necessary to add it) and no (guessing the sha1 hash is extremely unlikely).

Answer (score 1):

> Anything less than 12.8 quadrillion blocks, and your odds are
>   0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000%.
>
> With 12.8 quadrillion blocks, your odds are
>   0.00000000000001110223024625156540423631668090820313%.   To have 12.8 quadrillion blocks, you need 95 EB with 8 KB chunks, 190 EB with 16 KB
>   chunks, or 290 EB with 24 KB chunks.

Source: http://www.backupcentral.com/mr-backup-blog-mainmenu-47/13-mr-backup-blog/145-de-dupe-hash-collisions.html

See also: https://pthree.org/2014/03/06/the-reality-of-sha1/

In conclusion, yes, it's pretty safe.

That being said, make sure you [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) your hash, otherwise they can be reconstructed easily. How random and secure you need that salt to be is up to you.

Comment: would you still add the ?user=12345 parameter to the email?

Comment: It depends on how you're doing the lookup in the database. As long as the user ID and hash are positively linked in the DB, you can `SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE verification_hash = :hash` and get the ID that way (since we're assuming the hash is unique). By having two factors in the URL (id/hash, email/hash, etc), it prevents guessing a bunch of hashes and authorizing random users. Is it *needed*? Probably not. Is it useful to include something else? Probably.