# Two Git merges have a same commit hash ID

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

I have a problem in Git log; it seems that my team lost some changes.

I am questioning if two merge commits can share a same commit Hash ID. For example, a merge commit merges commit A and commit B yesterday. In Git log, another commit merges commit C and commit B today. Can it happen in normal situation?

[Update]
The Git log looks like below. I am not sure if it IS SHA-1 collision; my concern is that I can see two merges that have the same **ccccccc** commit. I hope it have my question clear.

```
=============================================================
commit yyyyyyy
Merge: aaaaaaa ccccccc
Author: Joe myself
Date:   Today some time

    Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/a-branch' into feature-branch

commit xxxxxxx
Merge: bbbbbbb ccccccc
Author: Kim
Date:   Two days ago some time

    Merge branch 'develop' of https://..... into her-branch

commit ccccccc
Merge: ddddddd eeeeeee
Author: Joe myself
Date:   Two days ago some time

    Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/another-branch' into a-branch
=============================================================
```

Comment: It's really unlikely as sha1 is a cryptographic hash function.

Comment: See this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867191/probability-of-sha1-collisions

Comment: possible duplicate of [How would git handle a SHA-1 collision on a blob?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392365/how-would-git-handle-a-sha-1-collision-on-a-blob)

Comment: How can it be a collision if each one of the 3 merge commits has a different id? A commit can be merged into many commits, you said it in your question: B is merged with both A and C, so B is ccccccc. My answer was correct: a collision cannot happen.

Comment: @FelipeC For sure, I don't think it's a SHA-1 collision. You got my point; my question was 'can a commit be merged into many commits?'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1867191/1790644) that explains the chances of a collision between two SHA-1 hashes; this situations is *very* unlikely, however still not entirely impossible.

Most visual git explorers will only show the first 8 digits of the hash, which while still very unlikely, is much more probable then the whole hash collision.

Run `git log` and examine your commits, my thought is that you may have misread something - I'll give you an award if you actually did get a collision :D

If you want, [edit] your post to add in the contents of the `git log` where you think you may have an issue for us to better understand your issue.

Cheers.

Comment: Downvoter, please explain your reasoning? If I missed something, or said something incorrectly, I would like to know. Cheers.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but to give a sense of "_very_" unlikely, if you were doing one commit per second since the Big Bang you'd have reason for concern about hash collisions.  To descend from the ludicrous to a merely ridiculous interval, your chances of a collision are down around 6.84227766e-20 if you'd been doing one per second since Lucy was an ape.   "Astronomically small" doesn't begin to cover that.  It's literally a rounding error on zero.