# In Git, how can two hashes point to one commit?

Tags: git, hash

I have some scripts that query our host (Gitlab) for all of a project's tags and the commit hashes that the tags point to.  Then it does some more work with those hashes.

This generally works, but I have one commit where I get a different hash than what is displayed with a git log on that commit.

The thing is, it's not exactly wrong.  The hash that is returned does let me checkout the correct commit:

```
>>git checkout 6a923
HEAD is now at ae67e044
```

and

```
>>git log -1 6a923
commit ae67e044359c86781fd7c1b74016f858f00584f8 (HEAD, tag: <correct tag>)
```

but it obviously doesn't serve when I want to do things like compare hashes later on.

I thought hashes were unique.  This seems to be some kind of alias hash.  What is going on here?

Additional Info:

```
>>git cat-file -p 6a923
object ae67e044359c86781fd7c1b74016f858f00584f8
type commit
tag <correct tag>
tagger <correct tagger> 1558448485 -0400
```

Comment: Just to be sure, by chance, do you have a tag named `6a923`?

Comment: I do not.  All the tags begin with a letter or a "1"

Comment: I wanted to ask the exact same thing. Could be a branch name as well.

Comment: What does `git log -1 6a923` say?

Comment: @kriegaex I've added log result to question as well.  It is not a branch or tag name.  Using the full hash gives the same results.

Comment: Show us in the question the output of: `git cat-file -p 6a923`

Comment: The hash is just a SHA1 of the contents of the commit. If both commits contain the same contents (somehow), or a collision occurs (which can happen in SHA1) they could have the same hash. I don't think they are guaranteed to be unique

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to get identical SHA1 hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479348/is-it-possible-to-get-identical-sha1-hash)

Comment: @Liam No.  I understand your point, but I'm not talking about two commits with the same hash.  I'm talking about two hashes pointing to the same commit.

Comment: Also see [Is there duplicated SHA commits? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34888175/is-there-duplicated-sha-commits) which lead to the above

Comment: That's impossible. A hash is a hash of the contents of the commit. A commit can't have **two contents**. I'm guessing you've got a weird named tag or branch

Answer (score 6, accepted):

6a923 is just an *annotated tag* that points to revision `ae67e04435`. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging

Comment: Exactly. The output of `git cat-file -p 6a923` implies it is a tag. If you issue `git cat-file -t 6a923`, it should print `tag`. But this result contradicts the OP's statement, claiming that it was not a tag name. It looks as though it is, however.

Comment: This is the right answer.  Thank you!  @kriegaex It doesn't contradict my statement.  It is not a tag name.  It is the hash of the annotated tag.  I did not know about annotated tags, and I definitely didn't know they had their own hashes.

Comment: Ah yes, of course, the annotated tag's hash. You should see the object representing the tag via `ls -l .git/objects/6a/923*` and be able to uncompress it via ZLIB, basically you should see pretty much the same as with `cat-file`, only starting with `tag <length>\0` or so.

Comment: You can verify my last statement by a Perl script with these 3 lines: `#!/bin/bash`, 
`FILE="$1"`, `perl -MCompress::Zlib -e 'undef $/; print uncompress(<>)' < "$FILE"`. Save it as `git-deflate.sh` and run `./git-deflate.sh .git/objects/6a/923...` (full name).

Comment: BTW, annotated tags must have their own objects with hashes because they need to be able to store comments like commits. My Git was a little rusty, but now it is coming back.

Comment: I noticed you are new here, @theredwagoneer. Please note that you should mark this correct answer as accepted in order to close it. Just click the grey checkmark, making it green. As soon as you have enough reputation points to upvote the answer, you can also do that.