# Git tag tags all the previous commits as well

Tags: git, github, git-tag

Currently I am trying to make my lib available on github. In two versions: `0.1` and `0.2`. I know that `pip` can find a package version by its tag on git, so I thought about tagging it.

When I do:

```
git add .
git commit -m "msg1"
git tag -a 0.1 -m "lib v0.1"
git push origin master --tag 0.1
```

The first commit is tagged 0.1

But when I change something in code, and I do pretty much the same:

```
git add .
git commit -m "msg2"
git tag -a 0.2 -m "lib v0.2"
git push origin master --tag 0.2
```

The last commit is tagged 0.2, but the first commit is tagged both 0.2 and 0.1. Am I doing something wrong? Or is it like it's supposed to be?

@Edit. This is how it looks on my git:

first commit:
[image]

second commit:
[image]

`Releases` tab:

[image]

Comment: What makes you think that "the first commit is tagged both 0.2 and 0.1"?

Comment: Check my question, I updated it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR

It's all fine.

#### Long

GitHub tries to hide a lot of Git's complexity from GitHub users.  This is, I believe, a mistake.  While Git is notoriously user-unfriendly (see, e.g., ["10 things I hate about Git"](https://stevebennett.me/2012/02/24/10-things-i-hate-about-git/) or [xkcd #1597](https://xkcd.com/1597/)), *some* of that complexity is truly necessary.<sup>1</sup>

In the case of Git tags, the thing to realize about tags is that any one tag is simply a human-readable name for some specific hash ID.  The hash IDs are those big ugly numberlike things that GitHub greys out and abbreviates and makes almost impossible to read.  In your screenshot, the two shown here are `a89f1cc` and `31a6a2d`.

These hash IDs are the *real* names of Git objects, i.e., the names that Git itself uses to *find* the objects' content.  These hash IDs are themselves produced by applying a cryptographic hash *to* the contents, so that the hash ID is a short(ish) key for a key-value database: given the key, which is guaranteed to be unique to those particular contents,<sup>2</sup> Git can look up the value and get the entire contents.  Since the two hashes are different, the two objects are necessarily different as well.  If the two objects were the same, the two hashes would be the same.

For annotated tag objects, it's actually necessary to go a little bit deeper: the contents of the annotated tag include the hash of the *target object*.  This is most easily done from the command line—again, GitHub hides the details, not that the command-line is all that clear either:

```
git rev-parse a89f1cc^{}
```

for instance would look up object `a89f1cc`, check whether it's an annotated tag object, and if so, follow it to whatever *other* object the tag itself names.  If `a89f1cc` is some other type of object, the suffix `^{}` has no effect.  We can also write:

```
git rev-parse a89f1cc^{commit}
```

which will find the *commit* object to which `a89f1cc` resolves, or produce an error, and in this particular case that would be what we want: this would either give us the full hash ID of `a89f1cc` itself, if it's already a commit, or produce the hash ID of the *commit* to which `a89f1cc` resolves, if it resolves to a commit, or else error-out.

More practically for you as someone using the system, given two tag names, you can just use the *names*:

```
git rev-parse v0.1^{commit}
```

and:

```
git rev-parse v0.2^{commit}
```

to find the commits to which the tags point.  (Some shells may require some kind of quoting around the hat `^` and/or brace `{...}` characters; this depends on whether you use bash, tcsh, PowerShell, or whatever.  You may need to adjust these command-line commands slightly to keep your shell happy.)

Resolving each of the two tag hashes to commits will tell you which commit or commits the two different tags name.  It's possible to give multiple tags to a single commit, but you didn't do that, so you will get two different commit hashes.  Those commits are the ones that `pip install` will check out, build, and install-from.

---

<sup>1</sup>[Albert Einstein is often paraphrased as saying *Everything should be made as simple as possible, but not simpler,*](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2011/05/13/einstein-simple/) although [Wikiquote says he actually wrote *It can scarcely be denied that the supreme goal of all theory is to make the irreducible basic elements as simple and as few as possible without having to surrender the adequate representation of a single datum of experience.*](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Albert_Einstein)

<sup>2</sup>This is a slight overstatement, depending on your Git version.  See [Hash collision in git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10434326/1256452) for details.

---

#### There's more to know if you're a Git user: tags vs branches, and the commit graph

If you're just going to install, the above is perhaps all that you care about.  However, as someone who uses Git itself, there's another thing to learn from this.

We saw above that a tag name resolves, via `git rev-parse` (which most Git commands do internally whenever it's appropriate) to a hash ID.  But the same is true—well, *mostly* true—of a *branch name* like `master` or `develop`.  We can run:

```
$ git rev-parse v2.16.0
e1c2c6b098dfb717a4a6ff7f3894d57343210a41
```

and get a hash ID like this, but we can also run:

```
$ git rev-parse master
ccdcbd54c4475c2238b310f7113ab3075b5abc9c
```

and get a hash ID.  This hash ID is the (one, single!) commit to which the name `master` points.  This is true of all of Git's *references:* branch names, tag names, remote-tracking names like `origin/master`, and so on, are all forms of *references*, and in Git, *every reference translates to one (1) hash ID.*

What's special about branch names is that they *change* over time.  They store one hash ID now, and then after you run `git commit`, some branch name stores a *new, different* hash ID.  This is in fact how branches grow: you tell Git that you would like to be *on* some branch, by running, e.g.:

```
git checkout master
```

after which `git status` says `on branch master`.  What it means to be *on a branch* is that `git commit` will *change* that branch name for you: Git will make a *new* commit, which will get some new, random-looking hash ID, and then Git will store that *new* commit's hash ID into the name `master`.

The underlying mechanism for this is the special name `HEAD` (in all capitals, although on Windows and Mac systems that do case folding, you can often use all-lowercase).  Git *attaches the word `HEAD` to a branch name* in order to remember which branch you've asked Git to be on.

If we had single uppercase letters for branch names, we could draw this out like so:

```
A <-B <-C   <-- master (HEAD)
```

which means that `HEAD` is attached to `master`, and the name `master` *points to* commit `C`—it contains the hash ID for commit `C`.  Commit `C` itself contains the hash ID for the earlier commit `B`, and commit `B` contains the hash ID for commit `A`.

In our case, our repository is tiny: it has just these three commits.  Commit `A` has no earlier commit—Git calls it a *root commit*—so it does not point anywhere.  This shows how Git works: it uses the *name* `master` to find the hash ID for the *current* commit `C`, and then uses the contents of commit `C` to find `C`'s *parent* commit `B`.  The contents of `B` let Git find `B`'s parent `A`, and `A` has no parent so now the action stops: Git shows you commit `C`, then `B`, then `A`, and stops.

Git, in other words, works *backwards*.

When you make a new commit `D`, Git creates this commit by recording a snapshot of all your code, recording the actual hash ID for earlier commit `C`, and then writing out the commit and getting its actual hash ID (whatever that is).  Git then uses `HEAD` to know to write the new hash ID into `master`, giving:

```
A <-B <-C <-D   <-- master (HEAD)
```

and now `master` names (points to) commit `D`.

Again, this is how branches normally move and grow.  The distinction between the *branch name* `master` and the *tag name* `v0.1` is that a branch name is *supposed to move*—supposed to change over time, to name the *last* commit for that branch—but a tag name *doesn't* move.  Once you have assigned a tag name to point to some particular commit, it sticks there: it keeps pointing to that commit.

The linkages from commit to commit form a *graph*, and it's this commit graph that really glues Git together.  GitHub tries to hide the commit graph from you.  Because Git is mostly about the graph—mere *files* just come along for the ride—this is a terrible disservice.  Understanding the commit graph is crucial to using Git.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a misunderstanding based on how github displays tags in its UI. When git displays a tag on a commit, that doesn't necessarily mean that commit is tagged with that version. To see the actual tags in github, you can click on the "Releases" tab.

Comment: Okay, in releases I have two separate versions. Does it mean, that when I `pip install -U git+https://github.com/frynio/calendarlib@0.2` it will install `0.2` version and if I `pip install -U git+https://github.com/frynio/calendarlib@0.1` it will install the `0.1` version? If so, then the tag only matters when I commit and push?