# Does identical commit HASH guarantee identical history in Git across different but related repos?

Tags: git, rebase

Usually, I add multiple related repos as remotes to my local git folder. Such as one for `upstream` and one for `myfork`.

And I sometimes do some work on `myfork.feature1`branch and then do a **cross-repo** rebase onto the latest `upstream.main` branch.

To achieve the rebase, I think git should do this:

1. Find the most recent **common base commit** of `myfork.feature1` and the `upstream.main` branches.
2. Pull in the latest commits from the `upstream.main` onto the `myfork.feature1`.
3. And then apply my commits since the common base commit on top of the latest commits just pulled in from `upstream.main`.

So the common base commit is the critical node.

My question is, if git finds 2 commits in both `myfork.feature1` and `upstream.main` branches that have the same SHA hash, is it safe to assume that is the common base commit? Are all the histories before that guaranteed to be the same?

Comment: "if git finds 2 commits in both myfork.feature1 and upstream.main branches that have the same SHA hash, can it safely assume that is the common base commit? Are all the histories before that guaranteed to be the same?" If two commits have the same hash, they are the same commit. That means they have the same "contents" and the same parent(s). I didn't understand any of the rest of what you said, but if that's the question, that's the answer.

Comment: Yes, they are the same. If you worry about hash collision in git, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434326/hash-collision-in-git.

Answer (score 4):

There are two different questions we can answer here:

1. Q: **Does Git assume that two commits with the same hash ID are in fact the same commit (and therefore have the same history behind them)?**

   A: **Yes.**  Git makes this assumption.
2. Q: **Is this assumption always valid?**  That is, are there any cases where we can generate a hash collision?

   A: **No.**  It is at least *theoretically* possible to have a hash collision.  Furthermore, SHA-1 is now nominally broken (as in, it's now feasible to attack SHA-1.)  The chances of any *two specific objects* having a collision are minuscule (2<sup>-160</sup>), but an attacker can craft particular files that will cause blob object hash ID collisions.

For more on question 2, see also [Hash collision in git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10434326/1256452) and [How does the newly found SHA-1 collision affect Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42433126/1256452)  Note that the [birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) means that as you add more objects to a pool of objects, the collision chance rises rather rapidly.  On the other hand, *commit* objects have a known and specific format: while the log message *can* contain arbitrary bytes, generating a *deliberate* collision will leave clear tracks, but to avoid *accidental* collisions, we must choose an acceptable error rate.<sup>1</sup>

Having done this, we can compute how many objects can be in the object store before we have reached this given probability level.  To achieve the same probability in a Git repository, we need to keep the number of keys (hash IDs) below about 1.71 x 10<sup>15</sup> (1.71 quadrillion).  **This is an enormously large repository**.  Each key is itself 20 bytes and each value is whatever size the average object size is.  Let's assume just 1000 bytes total, which is going to be ridiculously generously small for a repository this large, but makes our calculations easier: the repository would be about 1.7E18 bytes.  That's about 1546141 *terabytes*, or 1510 *petabytes*, or 1.5 *exabytes*.

(This is all *before* going to SHA-256, which makes things even safer.)

---

<sup>1</sup>We already do this for storage media.  For instance, physical disk drive manufacturers quote their undetected-error-rate at about 10<sup>-18</sup> or so.