# How many git tags can be created?

Tags: git, git-tag

I'm creating a git tags (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/git-tags?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser) per build. How many git tags can be created? Is there any limit?

Comment: I don't think there's a practical limit because tags are created using similar mechanism as branches (they're just refs)

Comment: They're stored as hashes just like other git objects. So similar answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434326/hash-collision-in-git.